# Select next non-matching element in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At the start, all `.show-this` sections are hidden, except for the first one.

Then, when a `.btn-next` is clicked, the preceding `.show-this` section should toggle the class `.visible`

HTML

```
<section class="show-this">
  ...
</section>

<button class="btn-next">Next</button>

<section class="show-this">
  ...
</section>

<button class="btn-next">Next</button>

<section class="show-this">
  ...
</section>
```

JQuery

```
$('.btn-next').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('.show-this').toggleClass('visible'); // doesn't work
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
$('.btn-next').click(function(){ 
$(this).next().toggleClass('visible'); 
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method to get the following sibling element of clicked *Next* button.

```js
$('.btn-next').click(function(){
  $(this).next('.show-this').toggleClass('visible').next('.btn-next').toggleClass('visible');
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```css
.show-this:not(:first-of-type), 
.btn-next:not(:first-of-type) {
  visibility:collapse;
}
.show-this.visible,
.btn-next.visible
{
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="show-this">
  ...
</section>

<button class="btn-next">Next</button>

<section class="show-this">
  ...
</section>

<button class="btn-next">Next</button>

<section class="show-this">
  ...
</section>
```

You could try to run the code snippet to test the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep only one next button and can show hide the sections like below.

```
$('.show-this:not(:first)').hide(); 

var current = 0;
$('.btn-next').click(function(){
    current++;
    $('.show-this').hide();  
    $(".show-this:eq("+current+")").show();   
});
```

Comment: Is there `:first` selector in [CSS specification](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors#Pseudo-classes)?!

Comment: `:first` is not a part of the CSS specification, its jQuery extension!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the preceding `.show-this` block, you have to use [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/). It will return the preceding sibling.

```
$('.btn-next').click(function(event){
  $(this).prev().toggleClass('visible');
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Check out this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/F3ddu19UlmmBBoMXMQKm?p=preview)